# Empty div is invisible

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a few css styles so that it fits on the page without having to scroll the page

```js
chatForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    //sends message
   
});
```

```css
#chat {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#messagebox {
    border: 0; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 90%;
    height:10%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
.submitButton {
    padding:10px;
    width: 10%;
    height:10%;
    background: #003;
    float:right;
    border:0;
    color:white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.submitButton:hover {
    background:#033
}
#messages {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
#messages p { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    background: lightblue; 
    color:white;
}
#messages p:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white; 
    color:lightblue;
}
#messages p .deleteButton { 
    background: white; 
    color:lightblue;
}
#messages p:nth-child(odd) .deleteButton{
    background: lightblue; 
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
    <div id="messages">
        <p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p>
    </div>
    <form id="chatForm">
        <input id="messagebox" required/>
        <button class="submitButton">
          Send
      </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Inside this div is nothing. However, it adds `<p>` whenever it receives a message from the server. Once it fills, it should have scroll bars that stop it from being too tall. However, this doesn't happen and it continues to fill. It's also invisible when empty. I have searched google and stackoverflow to no avail. Can someone help me understand why my css styles aren't working?

PS: The javascript is just there so it doesn't reload when you click the send button

Comment: Since you're using percentages, you have to make sure that the html/body tags also have a width and height of 100%.

Comment: ok whatever. Wait a minute, did you honestly just comment on my question so that you could reply to me?

Comment: @DaveNewton Also, it's listed in my developer story that I'm a mean person.

Comment: @DaveNewton For the intentions of the question that was asked, it seemed to be quite incorrect. Expecially since they were asking for a function called `reduce`, which according to the underline.js docs, was a function for arrays only. What's an `FWIW`???

Comment: Hm. Ok. Goodnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you didn't define this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And the same for any other element between `body` and `#chat`- the 100% height need a reference.

Without that, that DIV is only as high as it's content, so if there is no content, it will remain invisible....

Comment: Whymst does yu keep editting my stuff and not telling me what it is you did?!?!

Comment: @JermahlWhite If you click the *"Edited X mins ago"* above the editor's name, it shows you a diff of the of the changes.

Comment: Oh. oof. Thanks for telling me this

Answer (score 0):

Body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property, so the HTML element needs to have its height set as well.

However, the content of body will probably need to change dynamically. Setting height to 100% will accomplish your goal.

```js
chatForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    //sends message
   
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

#chat {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#messagebox {
    border: 0; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 90%;
    height:10%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
.submitButton {
    padding:10px;
    width: 10%;
    height:10%;
    background: #003;
    float:right;
    border:0;
    color:white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.submitButton:hover {
    background:#033
}
#messages {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
#messages p { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    background: lightblue; 
    color:white;
}
#messages p:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white; 
    color:lightblue;
}
#messages p .deleteButton { 
    background: white; 
    color:lightblue;
}
#messages p:nth-child(odd) .deleteButton{
    background: lightblue; 
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
    <div id="messages">
        <p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p><p>Example Message</p>
    </div>
    <form id="chatForm">
        <input id="messagebox" required/>
        <button class="submitButton">
          Send
      </button>
    </form>
</div>
```